# JavaScript setting variables?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain the second line of this function? is it setting two variables to = 0 at one time? i.e.  `var i = 0` and `var res = 0`?  If so, is it necessary to set `var i = 0` considering that it does that in `for(i = 0 ...` etc

```
function sumOnSteroids () {
    var i, res = 0;
    var number_of_params = arguments.length;
    for (i = o; i < number_of_params; i++) {
        res += arguments[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or it's an actual error in your code, but you are assigning i = o (the letter "o", not a zero.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the value of i will be undefined, the initializer only applies to "res" in that case. To assign the value you'd need:

```
var i = 0,
    res = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is setting two variables at once with the `var` keyword being applied to both, scoping them. Without the `var`, they would be properties of `window` (essentially globals).

The first one (`i`) would be `undefined` and the second one (`res`) would be `0`.

This is a powerful pattern because...

- `var` should be implicit, but it is not, so we only have to repeat it once.
- Less typing for you.
- Better for minifying (smaller file size).